# How to Export MS SQL DB from Docker-Linux to Access format

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, csv, docker

I have a MS SQL database which is currently up and running on my Mac within a Docker container that is hosting the Ubuntu Linux version of MS SQL Server.  I need to export the database to a format that can be imported into an Access (yes, *Access*) database.

Alternatively, I would need to export all 300+ tables to CSV, and hopefully would not need to do them one by one.  Is there any way to export all tables en masse to CSV?  But this is an alternative option.  I still prefer the Access-compatible export since our new SIS vendor apparently uses it. Thanks!

Comment: don't have a setup to test for a proper answer atm, but if you're not opposed to powershell, you could [export from sql server](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools) & [import to access](https://gist.github.com/tniedbala/8b21b9cf08aefacb210cbcd573ddf0b7)

Answer (score 0):

Follow [step by step guidance](https://www.easeus.com/sql-database-recovery/export-ms-sql-server-to-csv.html) using Microsoft SQL Server Management tool. 
Invoke context menu on your database Tasks -> Export Data..., where you can choose proper file name, encoding, delimiters.

[image]